# Running a node.js server on my VPS on port 3000 and the connection times out

Tags: node.js, vps

In hostgator I have a VPS running centOS. I installed NodeJS and screen.
I added the following code to a file named index.js:

```
//1
var http = require('http');

//2 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server running on port 3000.');
```

On 'screen:1' I run the following command:

```
node index.js
```

It gives me the console output stating 'Server running on port 3000.'
I switch to 'screen:0' and run the following command:

```
curl localhost:3000
```

and I get the following response:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>
```

Yet, when I try my server's IP address (substitute the xxx for a real IP address, cause I'm not disclosing my VPS IP address):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000
```

The page never comes up and eventually it times out.
I've tried various ports (8080, 7000) and to not avail.
Do I need to place the iOS project in a different directory.
Currently I have it in /root/Projects/NodeTutorial2/index.js.
What do I need to do to get a hello world response from my VPS?

Comment: I'm sure you just have your firewall running.  Stop iptables and see.  Also, make sure you're testing from a real internet connection.  A lot of mobile carriers do wonky things for traffic on non-HTTP ports.

Comment: I did:  root@mic [~/Projects/NodeTutorial2]# /etc/init.d/iptables save
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
root@mic [~/Projects/NodeTutorial2]# /etc/init.d/iptables stop
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: nat mangle filte[  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
root@mic [~/Projects/NodeTutorial2]#

Comment: Brad that worked! Please submit as answer!

Comment: Paul already did.  You can accept his answer.  And, don't forget to turn your firewall back on when you set up the appropriate rules.

Comment: I had saved the iptables and just ran 'iptables start'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a response from on the box, but not from other boxes, it's almost certainly a firewall issue.  Turning off IPTables or allowing the traffic in on the port in question is one option but an easier / more appropriate option is to simply have your app use port 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS).  You can either do that by listening to that port on the app directly, or by having a web server that acts as a reverse-proxy for you (e.g. NGINX or Apache).

Comment: If brad doesn't answer I'll give the answer to you. He posted first.

Comment: I just re-enabled the firewall. I'll see about using port 443 or port 80.